# What should I do about Composite Key?

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core-mvc, composite-key

Can anybody help me?

In my Detail.cshtml.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id = Model.PrimaryKey */ })
```

What is my Model.PrimaryKey?

It is my table

```
CREATE TABLE po_items (
PoNo INTEGER,
ItemNo INTEGER,
product_no INTEGER,
qty INTEGER,
net_price NUMERIC,
PRIMARY KEY (PoNo, ItemNo)
```

);

I have try this way, but it didn't work.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {  id = Model.PoNo + Model.ItemNo  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's easier than I thought :-) Just put 2 parameters into RouteValues in ActionLink so it generates a query string.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { PoNo= Model.PoNo, ItemNo= Model.ItemNo })
```

The url will be `Item/Edit/2?ItemNo=4`

So it's more about routing than anything else in my question. More on [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797444/ASP-NET-MVC-Edit-Primary-Key-Values-for-Composite)

Comment: I try your way .But it still didn't work. Maybe do we need define PoNo?

Comment: Also I have a doubt, When I use primary key,everything go will. But when I use Composite Keys everything will be wrong, like  Delete.cshtml ,Details.cshtml ,Edit.cshtml  they all can not work . It will show:
The webpage cannot be found
 
  HTTP 404 
 
    
Most likely causes:
•There might be a typing error in the address.
•If you clicked on a link, it may be out of date

Comment: Can you tell me what is the different between both ?

Comment: Can you please refer provided link, you can find the code over there so you can debug it and you will get better idea on that.